# Trying to move to different jsps from servlet depending on button press in form in index jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am attemting to move to different JSPs from button presses in my index(main) jsp throught the servlet where I check if a button was pressed and go to that servlet in my doGet. When i open my browser and click on the buttons i get an error saying:
 HTTP ERROR 405
Problem accessing /lab02a_dhilbert1/index. Reason:

```
HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
```

I'm not sure what the cause of this is and I'm required to move to the other pages through doGets.

I did have it working the way it is set up in a separate doPost but it is supposed to be done in a doGet. I've tried researching this issue and had trouble finding anything.

//servlet

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //go to correct jsp depending on button press
    if (req.getParameter("addNumbers") != null) {
        System.out.println("Add Numbers Servlet: doGet");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/_view/addNumbers.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
    else if (req.getParameter("multiplyNumbers") != null) {
        System.out.println("Multiply Numbers Servlet: doGet");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/_view/multiplyNumbers.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
    else if (req.getParameter("guessingGame") != null) {
        System.out.println("Guessing Game Servlet: doGet");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/_view/guessingGame.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Index Servlet: doGet");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/_view/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }   
}
```

//jsp

```
<body>
    <form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/index" method="post">
        This is the index view jsp 
        <br><input type="Submit" name="addNumbers" value="Add Numbers!!">
        <br><input type="Submit" name="multiplyNumbers" value="Multiply Numbers!!">
        <br><input type="Submit" name="guessingGame" value="Guessing Game!!">
    </form>
</body>
```

The index jsp should send button presses to the servlet and servlet should then call the correct jsp depending on which if any button was pressed.

Comment: your form method should match the servlet method. example method POST = doPost and method GET = doGet

Answer (score 0):

For post request must you have to write code into

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //go to correct jsp depending on button press
    if (req.getParameter("addNumbers") != null) {
        System.out.println("Add Numbers Servlet: doGet");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/_view/addNumbers.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
    else if (req.getParameter("multiplyNumbers") != null) {
        System.out.println("Multiply Numbers Servlet: doGet");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/_view/multiplyNumbers.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
    else if (req.getParameter("guessingGame") != null) {
        System.out.println("Guessing Game Servlet: doGet");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/_view/guessingGame.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Index Servlet: doGet");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/_view/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }   
}
```

Hope it will work perfect for post request.